# Command substitution inside double quotes

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, posix, command-substitution

I am attempting to write a bash parser. Many resources have referred to this [wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser)

One area I am getting stuck is why the following would work

```bsh
echo "$(echo "hi")"    # output => hi
```

According to the wiki, quotes are parsed before command substitution. In that case, why wouldn't there be an error parsing the first set of double quotes i.e.`"$(echo "`

Comment: "I am attempting to write a bash parser" That's the endeavour of a lifetime. Only bash can parse the bash language. Really. Besides the complexity and inconsistence of the shell language, its dynamic nature and the fact that your supposed to parse and run a script **line by line** means that you cannot parse a bash script without actually *running* it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linked article says:

> all characters except for **`$`**, `"`, `` ` `` and `\` lose any special meaning they might have

<sup>[emphasis mine]</sup>

What happens is `$` in `$(` in your code is *still* special. `$( )` is the syntax of command substitution. About command substitution, [from the same site](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

> Notably, once inside a command substitution, the shell begins an entirely new quoting context. That is, double quotes inside the substitution do not match up with double quotes outside the substitution.