# Why "$(findmnt | grep "\""proc"\"" | head -n 1)" is zero-length? (what is incorrect with escaping double quotes with `"\""` here?)

Tags: shell, quoting, escape-characters

I'm surprised that:

```
$ if [ -n "$(findmnt | grep "\""proc"\"" | head -n 1)" ]; then echo 1; else echo 2; fi
2
```

I've used `"\""` before IIRC after reading https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187452/446998, after all it works:

```
$ echo "1"\""2"\""3"
1"2"3
```

Why it doesn't in a first case?

Revisiting [How to escape quotes in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/how-to-escape-quotes-in-shell) and trying to follow accepted answer resulted in opposite issue: finding non-existing mounts:

```
$ if [ -n $'$(findmnt | grep "\proc111"\ | head -n 1)' ]; then echo 1; else echo 2; fi
1
```

It works w/out quotes for grep inside:

```
~$ if [ -n "$(findmnt | grep proc111 | head -n 1)" ]; then echo 1; else echo 2; fi
2
~$ if [ -n "$(findmnt | grep proc | head -n 1)" ]; then echo 1; else echo 2; fi
1
```

I've tried to read suggested [Escaping double quotes inside command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609946/escaping-double-quotes-inside-command-substitution) but could not immediately apply to my code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not seem to be that escaping double quotes is incorrect, but that there is no `"proc"` (enclosed in double quotes) being matched from the output of `findmnt`.

The default `findmnt` output only shows `/proc` for `TARGET` and `proc` for `SOURCE` and `FSTYPE` (at least in all the `findmnt` versions I've seen).

`findmnt -J` does output `"proc"` and so that would match with your expression, but then again it would make more sense to use a JSON parser like `jq`.

Comment: it was shown near the end of the question that is works for proc w/out quotes for me on my PC.

Comment: That's expected since `grep` is not searching for literal double quotes in the pattern, which does not exist in the default output of `findmnt`.